# How to add a vertical line to a plot from the "mirt" package?

Tags: r

I used the `mirt` package to create an item information plot.

```
library(mirt)
model <- mirt(data, 1, itemtype = '2PL')
plot(model, type = 'infotrace', facet_items = FALSE)
```

I try to add a vertical line to the plot at x = 1. 
However, the function `abline(v = 1)` does not work.

Comment: did you try any of the hints given in your recently deleted question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473838/how-to-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-plot-generated-by-the-plot-function-in-the-mi#comment105126153_59473838

Comment: ... so from the third link id try `p = plot(model, type = 'infotrace', facet_items = FALSE); p + latticeExtra::layer(panel.abline(v = 1))` [untested]

Answer (score 2):

You can try below, I used an example dataset from mirt package:

```
library(lattice)
library(mirt)
library(latticeExtra)

data <- expand.table(LSAT7)
mod1 <- mirt(data, 1)
plot(mod1,type = 'infotrace', facet_items = FALSE)
trellis.focus("panel",1,1)
panel.abline(v=1)
trellis.unfocus()
```

[image]

In addition, the suggestion by @user20650 also works:

```
p = plot(mod1, type = 'infotrace', facet_items = FALSE)
p + latticeExtra::layer(panel.abline(v = 1))
```